# JavaDStream print() function not printing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark streaming.
I followed the tutorial from this link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

When I ran the code, I could see the line was being processed, but I could not see output with timestamp.

I only could see this log:

```
14/10/22 15:24:17 INFO scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Stream 0 received 0 blocks
14/10/22 15:24:17 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1414005857000 ms
.....
```

Also I was trying to save last DStream with forEachRDD function call, the data was not being stored.
If anyone can help me with this, would be a great help..

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem, here is how I solved:

change

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local")
```

to

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
```

It's a mistake to `setMaster("local")`, which will not calculate actually.

Hope this is the problem you meet.

Answer (score 0):

The print is working as evidenced by the `.....` separator, only there's nothing to print: the DStream is empty. The log provided actually shows that: `Stream 0 received 0 blocks`.

Make sure you're sending data correctly to your Receiver.

Comment: I was getting data but after 20 seconds. Do you know how to do streaming with Kafka. Now I stuck with kafka. I am getting the data but it is not going till print() function of RDD.

Comment: Hard to say. I guess you need to post a new question with the code you're using.

Answer (score -1):

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]") works
```

`local[*]`: '`*`' means create the worker thread as the same number as the kernel number of CPU 
if using "local", no worker is created, why default is not 1,  isn't it a issue?
refer to.
[What does setMaster `local[*]` mean in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356143/what-does-setmaster-local-mean-in-spark)

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or comment to another answer?