# What does setMaster `local[*]` mean in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I found some code to start spark locally with:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
val ctx = new SparkContext(conf)
```

What does the `[*]` mean?

Answer (score 94):

From the [doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/):

```
./bin/spark-shell --master local[2]
```

> The `--master` option specifies the master URL for a distributed
>   cluster, or `local` to run locally with one thread, or `local[N]` to run
>   locally with N threads. You should start by using local for testing.

And from [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls):

> `local[*]`    Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical
>   cores on your machine.

Answer (score 87):

> Master URL    Meaning

---

**local** : Run Spark locally with one worker thread (i.e. no parallelism at all).

---

**local[K]** :  Run Spark locally with K worker threads (ideally, set this to the number of cores on your machine).

---

**local[K,F]** :    Run Spark locally with K worker threads and F maxFailures (see spark.task.maxFailures for an explanation of this variable)

---

**local[*]**  :     Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine.

---

**local[*,F]**  :  Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine and F maxFailures.

---

**spark://HOST:PORT**  :    Connect to the given Spark standalone cluster master. The port must be whichever one your master is configured to use, which is 7077 by default.

---

**spark://HOST1:PORT1,HOST2:PORT2**  : Connect to the given Spark standalone cluster with standby masters with Zookeeper. The list must have all the master hosts in the high availability cluster set up with Zookeeper. The port must be whichever each master is configured to use, which is 7077 by default.

---

**mesos://HOST:PORT**  :    Connect to the given Mesos cluster. The port must be whichever you have configured to use, which is 5050 by default. Or, for a Mesos cluster using ZooKeeper, use mesos://zk://.... To submit with --deploy-mode cluster, the HOST:PORT should be configured to connect to the MesosClusterDispatcher.

---

**yarn**  :     Connect to a YARN cluster in client or cluster mode depending on the value of --deploy-mode. The cluster location will be found based on the HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR variable.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: Is there any way we can print available cores on given environment ? like system.getEnv("prop....")

Comment: 'locally' means that it will be run on a single machine with multiple cores?

Comment: @RakeshK yes one machine

Answer (score 17):

Some additional Info

Do not run Spark Streaming programs locally with master configured as "local" or "local[ 1]". This allocates only one CPU for tasks and if a receiver is running on it, there is no resource left to process the received data. Use at least "local[ 2]" to have more cores.

From -Learning Spark: Lightning-Fast Big Data Analysis

Answer (score 6):

[Master URL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#running-the-examples-and-shell)

You can run Spark in local mode using `local, local[n]` or the most general `local[*]` for the master URL.

The URL says how many threads can be used in total:

`local` uses 1 thread only.

`local[n]` uses n threads.

`local[*]` uses as many threads as the number of processors available to the Java virtual machine (it uses `Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()` to know the number).

`local[N, maxFailures]` (called local-with-retries) with `N` being `*` or the number of threads to use (as explained above) and maxFailures being the value of `spark.task.maxFailures`.

Comment: Dead link = https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-local.html

Comment: Removed dead Link

Answer (score 4):

You can run Spark in local mode using local, local[n] or the most general local[*] for the master URL.

The URL says how many threads can be used in total:-

local uses 1 thread only.

local[n] uses n threads.

local[*] uses as many threads as your spark local machine have, where you are running your application.

you can check by lscpu in your Linux machine

[ie@mapr2 ~]$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
**CPU(s):                56**
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-55
Thread(s) per core:    2

if your machine has 56 cores means CPU then your spark jobs will be partitioned in 56 part.

NOTE:- there may be the case that in your spark cluster the **spark-defaults.conf** file has limited the partition value with the default value (like 10 or else) then your partitioned will be the same as default value has been set in config.

local[N, maxFailures] (called local-with-retries) with N being * or the number of threads to use (as explained above) and maxFailures being the value of spark.task.maxFailures.

Answer (score -2):

without * spark will use single thread.

With * spark will use all the available threads the run this program

Comment: Isn't this already mentioned in all the other answers submitted years ago?