# Spark uses only one core when using forEachRemaining

Tags: apache-spark

I'm still new to Spark. I wrote this code to parse large string list.

I had to use `forEachRemaining` because I had to initialize some non-serializable objects in each partition.

```
    JavaRDD<String> lines=initRetriever();
    lines.foreachPartition(iter->{
        Obj1 obj1=initObj1()
        MyStringParser parser=new MyStringParser(obj1);
        iter.forEachRemaining(str->{
            try {
                parser.parse(str);
            } catch (ParsingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        System.out.print("all parsed");
        obj1.close();
    });
```

I believe Spark is all about parallelism. But this program uses only a single thread on my local machine. Did I do something wrong? Missing configuration? Or maybe the `iter` doesn't allow it to execute all in parallel.

#### EDIT

I have no configuration files for Spark.

That's how I initialize Spark

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName(AbstractSparkImporter.class.getCanonicalName())
                .setMaster("local");
```

I run it on IDE and using `mvn:exec` command.

Comment: Could you please add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alberto-Bonsanto indicated, using `local[*]` triggers Spark to use all available threads. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32356252/1019952).

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName(AbstractSparkImporter.class.getCanonicalName())
                .setMaster("local[*]");
```