# Spark - Error "A master URL must be set in your configuration" when submitting an app

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an Spark app which runs with no problem in local mode,but have some problems when submitting to the Spark cluster.

The error msg are as follows:

```
16/06/24 15:42:06 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, cluster-node-02): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at GroupEvolutionES$$anonfun$6.apply(GroupEvolutionES.scala:579)
    at GroupEvolutionES$$anonfun$6.apply(GroupEvolutionES.scala:579)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1595)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:401)
    at GroupEvolutionES$.<init>(GroupEvolutionES.scala:37)
    at GroupEvolutionES$.<clinit>(GroupEvolutionES.scala)
    ... 14 more

16/06/24 15:42:06 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, cluster-node-02): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class GroupEvolutionES$
    at GroupEvolutionES$$anonfun$6.apply(GroupEvolutionES.scala:579)
    at GroupEvolutionES$$anonfun$6.apply(GroupEvolutionES.scala:579)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1595)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the above code, `GroupEvolutionES` is the main class. The error msg says "A master URL must be set in your configuration", but I have provided the "--master" parameter to `spark-submit`.

Anyone who knows how to fix this problem?

Spark version: 1.6.1

Comment: Could you please paste the command here that you are using to submit the script.

Comment: Have you provided the spark master URL ?

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava spark-submit --class GroupEvolutionES --master spark://cluster-node-nn1:7077 --jars $mypath myapp.jar

Comment: @KSHITIJKULSHRESTHA Yes.

Comment: I ran into this in my `Spark` project's **unit-tests** ([`DataFrameSuiteBase`](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki/DataFrameSuiteBase)). From **@Dazzler**'s answer, I understood that I must move `DataFrame`-creation inside `test(..) { .. }` suites. But also just **declaring `DataFrame`s to be `lazy`** fixes it (love `Scala`!). This has been pointed out be **@gyuseong** in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51376513/3679900) below

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Where is the sparkContext object defined, is it inside the main function?

I too faced the same problem, the mistake which i did was i initiated the sparkContext outside the main function and inside the class.

When I initiated it inside the main function, it worked fine.

Comment: Spark really needs to improve: it just shows very confusing and uninformative error messages when something wrong happends

Comment: This is a workaround and not a solution, What if I want to created a Singletion Context and create a separate layer of Context apart from main function for multiple applications?

Comment: "Note that applications should define a `main()` method instead of extending `scala.App`. Subclasses of `scala.App` may not work correctly." [Spark 2.1.0 Manual](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications)

Comment: Pay attention to where you try to `getOrCreate()` a context should be created at driver level and passed on to executor level as needed.

Answer (score 218):

The TLDR:

```
.config("spark.master", "local")
```

[a list of the options for spark.master in spark 2.2.1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/submitting-applications.html#master-urls)

I ended up on this page after trying to run a simple Spark SQL java program in local mode. To do this, I found that I could set spark.master using:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
.config("spark.master", "local")
.getOrCreate();
```

An update to my answer:

To be clear, this is not what you should do in a production environment. In a production environment, spark.master should be specified in one of a couple other places: either in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf (this is where cloudera manager will put it), or on the command line when you submit the app. (ex spark-submit --master yarn).

If you specify spark.master to be 'local' in this way, spark will try to run in a single jvm, as indicated by the comments below. If you then try to specify --deploy-mode cluster, you will get an error 'Cluster deploy mode is not compatible with master "local"'. This is because setting spark.master=local means that you are NOT running in cluster mode.

Instead, for a production app, within your main function (or in functions called by your main function), you should simply use:

```
SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
.getOrCreate();
```

This will use the configurations specified on the command line/in config files.

Also, to be clear on this too: --master and "spark.master" are the exact same parameter, just specified in different ways. Setting spark.master in code, like in my answer above, will override attempts to set --master, and will override values in spark-defaults.conf, so don't do it in production. Its great for tests though.

also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42622585/2255242). 
which links to [a list of the options for spark.master](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) and what each one actually does.

[a list of the options for spark.master in spark 2.2.1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/submitting-applications.html#master-urls)

Comment: yes , adding 
".config("spark.master", "local")" worked for me also .

Comment: Thanks this worked for me - but could someone explain to a newbie (me) what the .config("spark.master", "local") is doing? Will my code still be fine to compile into a jar and run in production?

Comment: @user1761806 while many of the answers report this as a fix, it fundamentally changes the way spark processes, only using a single JVM.  Local is used for local testing and is not the correct solution to fix this problem if you intend to deploy to a cluster.  I had similar issues and the accepted answer was the correct solution to my problem.

Answer (score 66):

Worked for me after replacing

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SOME APP NAME");
```

with

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SOME APP NAME").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g");
```

Found this solution on some other thread on stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this solve the OP's question? This creates a local cluster in this JVM, not attach to a standalone elsewhere.

Comment: This does solve the issue. I don't know (yet) about the implications of `setMaster("local[2]")` (would be nice to have an explanation), but this answer can be considered the solution for the issue.

Comment: I just edited the answer to include this information :)

Comment: What should be the `master` value for databricks AWS cluster?

Answer (score 30):

The default value of "spark.master" is spark://HOST:PORT, and the following code tries to get a session from the standalone cluster that is running at **HOST:PORT**, and expects the HOST:PORT value to be in the spark config file.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("SomeAppName")
    .getOrCreate();
```

"*org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration*"  states that **HOST:PORT** is not set in the spark configuration file.

To not bother about value of "HOST:PORT", set **spark.master** as **local**

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("SomeAppName")
    .config("spark.master", "local")
    .getOrCreate();
```

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) is the link for list of formats in which master URL can be passed to spark.master

Reference : [Spark Tutorial](https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark-tutorial/) - [Setup Spark Ecosystem](https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/how-to-configure-apache-spark-ecosystem/)

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my day!

Answer (score 11):

just add `.setMaster("local")` to your code as shown below:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Second").setMaster("local")
```

It worked for me ! Happy coding !

Comment: Nice hat. In java it's `SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application").master("local").getOrCreate();`

Answer (score 7):

If you are running a standalone application then you have to use `SparkContext` instead of `SparkSession`

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Samples").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val textData = sc.textFile("sample.txt").cache()
```

Comment: `.setMaster("local")` is the key to solve the issue for me

Comment: What if I have it set but still have this error? @tom10271

Comment: @AnnaLeonenko I am sorry but I have stopped developing Spark application for a year already, I cannot recall my memory. But I guess your master node is not local which is managed by spark but yarn?

Comment: @AnnaLeonenko I have checked my settings. When I was running it locally for development and I only use Spark to manage master node, then I will set it to `local` or `local[*]`. When I deploy it to AWS EMR, it uses Yarn for coordination, then I set master as `yarn`

Answer (score 4):

How does spark context in your application pick the value for spark master?

- You either provide it explcitly withing `SparkConf` while creating SC.
- Or it picks from the `System.getProperties` (where SparkSubmit earlier put it after reading your `--master` argument).

Now, `SparkSubmit` runs on the driver -- which in your case is the machine from where you're executing the `spark-submit` script. And this is probably working as expected for you too.

However, from the information you've posted it looks like you are creating a spark context in the code that is sent to the executor -- and given that there is no `spark.master` system property available there, it fails. (And you shouldn't really be doing so, if this is the case.)

Can you please post the `GroupEvolutionES` code (specifically where you're creating `SparkContext(s)`).

Comment: Yes. I should have created the SparkContext in the `main` functions of GroupEvolutionES (which I didn't).

Comment: This is a workaround and not a solution, What if I want to created a Singletion Context and create a separate layer of Context apart from main function for multiple applications? Any comments on how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

Replacing :

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SOME APP NAME");
WITH
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SOME APP NAME").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g");
```

Did the magic.

Comment: Isn't your solution exactly the same as to what @Sachin posted?

Comment: why local[2] can you explain

Comment: about local[2] -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356143/what-does-setmaster-local-mean-in-spark

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, Here is my code before modification :

```
package com.asagaama

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

/**
  * Created by asagaama on 16/02/2017.
  */
object Word {

  def countWords(sc: SparkContext) = {
    // Load our input data
    val input = sc.textFile("/Users/Documents/spark/testscase/test/test.txt")
    // Split it up into words
    val words = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    // Transform into pairs and count
    val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey { case (x, y) => x + y }
    // Save the word count back out to a text file, causing evaluation.
    counts.saveAsTextFile("/Users/Documents/spark/testscase/test/result.txt")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    countWords(sc)
  }

}
```

And after replacing :

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount")
```

With :

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount").setMaster("local[*]")
```

It worked fine !

Answer (score 2):

```
var appName:String ="test"
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g");
val sc =  SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
```

Comment: This solution was what worked for me. Thanks for putting it up. @Mario.

Answer (score 2):

try this

make trait

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
trait SparkSessionWrapper {
   lazy val spark:SparkSession = {
      SparkSession
        .builder()
        .getOrCreate()
    }
}
```

extends it

```
object Preprocess extends SparkSessionWrapper {
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this SparkContext constructor instead, and errors were gone:

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "MyApp")
```

Answer (score 1):

We are missing the **setMaster("local[*]")** to set. Once we added then problem get resolved.

**Problem:**

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Hive Example")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
```

**solution:**

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Hive Example")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried this option in learning Spark processing with setting up Spark context in local machine. Requisite
1)Keep Spark sessionr running in local
2)Add Spark maven dependency
3)Keep the input file at root\input folder
4)output will be placed at \output folder.
Getting max share value for year. down load any CSV from yahoo finance
https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/CAPPL.BO/history/
Maven dependency and Scala code below -

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>   

object MaxEquityPriceForYear {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ShareMaxPrice").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g");
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
    val input = "./input/CAPPL.BO.csv"
    val output = "./output"
    sc.textFile(input)
      .map(_.split(","))
      .map(rec => ((rec(0).split("-"))(0).toInt, rec(1).toFloat))
      .reduceByKey((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))
      .saveAsTextFile(output)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using following code

```
 val sc = new SparkContext(master, "WordCount", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))
```

Then replace with following lines

```
  val jobName = "WordCount";
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(jobName);
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

---

In Spark 2.0 you can use following code

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
  .master("local[*]")// need to add
  .getOrCreate()
```

You need to add .master("local[*]") if runing local here * means all node , you can say insted of 8 1,2 etc

You need to set Master URL if on cluster

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide Spark configuration in JavaSparkContext then you get this error. 
That is:
JavaSparkContext sc  = new JavaSparkContext();

Solution: Provide JavaSparkContext sc  = new JavaSparkContext(conf);