# Running first program in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run my first program in Spark with scala. Trying to read a csv file and display.

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark._
import java.io._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j._

object df extends App{

 val spark=SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
 val drf=spark.read.csv("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/scala-datasets/Scala-and-
 Spark-Bootcamp-master/Spark DataFrames/CitiGroup2006_2008")
 drf.head(5)
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
   Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
    17/04/29 23:10:53 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
    17/04/29 23:10:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop 
    library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    17/04/29 23:10:57 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your 
    configuration at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>
    (SparkContext.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
at df$.delayedEndpoint$df$1(df.scala:11)
at df$delayedInit$body.apply(df.scala:9)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
at df$.main(df.scala:9)
at df.main(df.scala)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032169/error-initializing-sparkcontext-a-master-url-must-be-set-in-your-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You missed `.master()` function call. for example if you want to run in `local mode` following is the solution :

```
object df extends App{
 val spark=SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
 val drf=spark.read.csv("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/scala-datasets/Scala-and-
 Spark-Bootcamp-master/Spark DataFrames/CitiGroup2006_2008")
 drf.head(5)
}
```

And the error log clearly says that

```
17/04/29 23:10:57 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your 
    configuration at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>
    (SparkContext.scala:379)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As previous comment said you should setup master for your spark context, in your case it should be local[1] or local[*]. Also you should set a appName.
You can avoid master and appName specification via code using spark-submit with keys.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object df extends App{
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("example").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    val drf = spark.read.csv("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/scala-datasets/Scala-and-Spark-Bootcamp-master/Spark DataFrames/CitiGroup2006_2008")
    drf.head(5)
  }
}
```