# Apache spark master URL error running in idea intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am using intellij idea for spark application in scala.
i am not sure why i am getting below error.

Code:

```
package batch

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object BatchJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Lambda with Spark")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sourceFile = "file:///E:/Boxes/data.tsv"
    val input = sc.textFile(sourceFile)

    input.foreach(println)
  }

}
```

Error:

```
**Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration**
```

Comment: Does this work if you comment out the if statement?

Comment: @TerryDactyl: its throwing error as : Error:(22, 31) not found: value conf
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark - Error "A master URL must be set in your configuration" when submitting an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008330/spark-error-a-master-url-must-be-set-in-your-configuration-when-submitting-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running Spark on Intellij (in local mode), You should set master for the Spark config object, too:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Lambda with Spark").setMaster("local[*]")
```

Comment: This will override master configuration if this is called from spark-submit, check my answer which I think is better

Comment: @CarlosVerdes sure, but the question is about running Spark on Intellij, not using spark-submit command!

Comment: I run my code inside intellij, check my answer I tested today and is working :)

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers force the driver to run in local with a number of cores.
This is fine to do a quick test on local but is not good if you want to execute this driver with Spark submit command.

The trick that worked for me is to create a default conf and check if master is defined.
If it's not then I assume is a local test and I force master = local.

```
val SPARK_MASTER = "spark.master"
val DEFAULT_MASTER = "local[*]"

// get default conf
val defaultConf = new SparkConf()

// if master is not defined then set default to local
if(!defaultConf.contains(SPARK_MASTER)) defaultConf.setMaster(DEFAULT_MASTER)

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(defaultConf).getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error says ,u have to set a master url for spark to run.If you are running inside ide or locally you should make SparkConf object like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Lambda with Spark").setMaster(local[*])
```

for running on clusters you can use 'yarn' as the master.