# Spark - A master URL must be set in your configuration” when trying to run an app

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know this question has a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008330/spark-error-a-master-url-must-be-set-in-your-configuration-when-submitting-a)
, but my use case is a little specific. I want to run my Spark job (compiled to a .jar) on an EMR (via Spark submit) and give 2 options like this:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster <rest of command>
```

To achieve this, I wrote the code like this:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()
```

However this gives the error during building the jar:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
```

So what's a workaround? How do I set these 2 variables in code so that the `master` and `deploy mode` options are taken up while submitting; yet I should be able to use the variables `sc` and `spark` in my code (e.g:- val x = spark.read())

Answer (score 0):

You could simply access command-line arguments simply as below and pass as many values as you want.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test App")
  .master(args(0))
  .getOrCreate()


 spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster master-url
```

If you need something more fancy command-line parser then you can take a look here https://github.com/scopt/scopt