# How can I specify number of ALS worker threads in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I use this simple code to calculate recommendation from command line java app:

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("SomeAppName")
            .config("spark.master", "local")
            .config("spark.executor.instances",1) // ??
            .config("spark.executor.cores",3) // ??
            .getOrCreate();
    JavaRDD<Rating> ratingsRDD = spark
            .read().textFile(args[0]).javaRDD()
            .map(Rating::parseRating);
    Dataset<Row> ratings = spark.createDataFrame(ratingsRDD, Rating.class);
    ALS als = new ALS()
            .setMaxIter(1)
            .setRegParam(0.01)
            .setUserCol("userId")
            .setItemCol("movieId")
            .setRatingCol("rating");
    ALSModel model = als.fit(ratings);
    model.setColdStartStrategy("drop");
    Dataset<Row> rowDataset = model.recommendForAllUsers(50);
```

But this code uses just 100% of CPU (800% CPU usage observed with other apps), how can I increase number of threads correctly?

Comment: (in other words don't use `local` master)

Comment: I want 8 kernels, what else should I specify?

Comment: Quoting [linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46676635/10465355): _`local[K]` : Run Spark locally with K worker threads (ideally, set this to the number of cores on your machine)_ therefore `local[8]`.

Comment: If you put it as an anwer, i'll accept it