# How to set standalone Spark configurations to locally run MLlib spark examples?

Tags: java, apache-spark, configuration, local, apache-spark-standalone

I wanna run *Spark MLlib examples* locally on my PC (I think it names standalone). I want to run **JavaWord2VecExample.java**. this file configuration is set for sessions that runs the Spark on some workers with a one Master but I want to run the class just on my PC (locally). the original class source code is here:

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.ml;

// $example on$
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2VecModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
// $example off$

public class JavaWord2VecExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("JavaWord2VecExample")
      .getOrCreate();

    // $example on$
    // Input data: Each row is a bag of words from a sentence or document.
    List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
      RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("Hi I heard about Spark".split(" "))),
      RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("I wish Java could use case classes".split(" "))),
      RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("Logistic regression models are neat".split(" ")))
    );
    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
      new StructField("text", new ArrayType(DataTypes.StringType, true), false, Metadata.empty())
    });
    Dataset<Row> documentDF = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

    // Learn a mapping from words to Vectors.
    Word2Vec word2Vec = new Word2Vec()
      .setInputCol("text")
      .setOutputCol("result")
      .setVectorSize(3)
      .setMinCount(0);

    Word2VecModel model = word2Vec.fit(documentDF);
    Dataset<Row> result = model.transform(documentDF);

    for (Row row : result.collectAsList()) {
      List<String> text = row.getList(0);
      Vector vector = (Vector) row.get(1);
      System.out.println("Text: " + text + " => \nVector: " + vector + "\n");
    }
    // $example off$
    List<String> text = row.getList(0);
      Vector vector = (Vector) row.get(1);
      System.out.println("Text: " + text + " => \nVector: " + vector + "\n");
    spark.stop();
  }
}
```

I know that, if I want to run examples on the local PC, I should replace **SparkConf** with **SparkSession**. so, I tried and currently source code is:

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.ml;

// $example on$
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2VecModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
// $example off$

public class JavaWord2VecExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {


    SparkConf spark = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("JavaWord2VecExample")
            .set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "1")
            .setMaster("spark://master:7077");

    // $example on$
    // Input data: Each row is a bag of words from a sentence or document.
    List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
      RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("Hi I heard about Spark".split(" "))),
      RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("I wish Java could use case classes".split(" "))),
      RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("Logistic regression models are neat".split(" ")))
    );
    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
      new StructField("text", new ArrayType(DataTypes.StringType, true), false, Metadata.empty())
    });
    Dataset<Row> documentDF = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

    // Learn a mapping from words to Vectors.
    Word2Vec word2Vec = new Word2Vec()
      .setInputCol("text")
      .setOutputCol("result")
      .setVectorSize(3)
      .setMinCount(0);

    Word2VecModel model = word2Vec.fit(documentDF);
    Dataset<Row> result = model.transform(documentDF);

    for (Row row : result.collectAsList()) {
      List<String> text = row.getList(0);
      Vector vector = (Vector) row.get(1);
      System.out.println("Text: " + text + " => \nVector: " + vector + "\n");
    }
    // $example off$
    List<String> text = row.getList(0);
      Vector vector = (Vector) row.get(1);
      System.out.println("Text: " + text + " => \nVector: " + vector + "\n");
    spark.stop();
  }
}
```

so, some error displayed:

> Error: java:cannot find symbol

for methods *createDataFrame()* and *stop()*.

I am new in java and Spark. plz help me to fix these errors.
thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create `SparkSession` directly , and create *dataframe* from `SparkSession`

```java
SparkSession spark= SparkSession.builder()
                                .appName("JavaWord2VecExample")
                                .master("spark://master:7077")
                                .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", true)
                                .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", true)
                                .config("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "1")
                                .getOrCreate();
```

Comment: Thank you @howie. It solved my problem. but I replaced *"spark://master:7077"* with *"local[4]"*. it means spark runs on local PC with 4 cores.

Comment: Actually, it mean run on core #4

Comment: local[n] : Run Spark locally with n worker threads (ideally, set this to the number of cores on your machine). @howie

Comment: You can find complementary explanations at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356143/what-does-setmaster-local-mean-in-spark