# How to debug MemoryError in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to download some xml files (50MBs each - about 3000 = 150GBs), process them and upload to BigQuery using pyspark. For the development purpose I was using jupyter notebook and small amount of files 10. I wrote pretty complex code setup cluster on dataproc. My daproc cluster has 6TBs of HDFSs, 10 nodes (each 4 cores) and 120GBs of RAM.

```py
def context():
    import os
    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 pyspark-shell'
    import pyspark
    conf = pyspark.SparkConf()

    conf = (conf.setMaster('local[*]')
            .set('spark.executor.memory', '4G')
            .set('spark.driver.memory', '45G')
            .set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '10G')
            .set("spark.python.profile", "true"))
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
    return sc
```

```py
def job(sc):
    print("Job started")
    RDDread = sc.wholeTextFiles("s3a://custom-bucket/*/*.gz")
    models = RDDread.flatMap(process_xmls).groupByKey()
    tracking_all = (models.filter(lambda x: x[0] == TrackInformation)
                    .flatMap(lambda x: x[1])
                    .map(lambda model: (model.flight_ref, model))
                    .groupByKey())
    tracking_merged = tracking_all.map(lambda x: x[1]).map(merge_ti)
    flight_plans = (models.filter(lambda x: x[0] == FlightPlan).flatMap(lambda x: x[1]).map(lambda fp: (fp.flight_ref, fp)))
    fps_tracking = tracking_merged.union(flight_plans).groupByKey().filter(lambda x: len(x[1]) == 2)
    in_bq_batch = 1000
    n = fps_tracking.count()
    parts = ceil(n / in_bq_batch)
    many_n = fps_tracking.repartition(parts).mapPartitions(upload_fpm2)
    print("Job ended")
    return fps_tracking, tracking_merged, flight_plans, models, many_n
```

After 200 messages `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]` I'm getting 2 errors: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and MemoryError, mostly MemoryError. I thought that I have just 2 partitions after RDDread, so I modified code for: sc.wholeTextFiles("s3a://custom-bucket/*/*.gz", minPartitions=40) -> And it got broke even faster. I was adding persistent(DISK) function in some random places.

```
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 684, in loads
    return s.decode("utf-8") if self.use_unicode else s
MemoryError
```

```
19/05/20 14:09:23 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]
19/05/20 14:09:30 ERROR org.apache.spark.util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for /opt/conda/default/bin/python
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

What I am doing wrong and how to debug my code?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running spark in local mode (local[*]). This means that you are using a single jvm with 45G of RAM (spark.driver.memory) and that all your worker threads run within that jvm. The spark.executor.memory option has no effect [What does setMaster `local[*]` mean in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356143/what-does-setmaster-local-mean-in-spark).

You should set up your spark master either to the yarn scheduler, or if you have no yarn use standalone mode https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html.