# Spark-submit local mode in spark master

Tags: apache-spark

I have a doubt regarding spark-submit for which I am not getting a clear solution. Running spark-submit in local machine with master as local[*] will run it in local mode is what I am clear about but what if I run the same master as local[*] in the gateway node or in the master node itself. Is my application consumes the entire cluster or is still running in local mode in that particular machine.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> what if I run the same master as local[] in the gateway node or in the master node itself. Is my application consumes the entire cluster or is still running in local mode in that particular machine.

Answer : 
local mode in that particular machine ( gateway node or in the master node). since you are not using yarn as master. just try a sample test on this to prove the point.

[image: local mode for gateway node or in the master node where ever you are running.]

For more details see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53711815/647053)

another way to see that is spark ui.. in environment tab it will display the details about where it is running... see the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: hi was it useful ?  if you are okay please care to [accept answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: was it useful ?

Answer (score 0):

In that case it will use the resources of ***gateway node*** or the ***master node***.
Cluster comes to role only when any of the cluster manager (E.g. **YARN**, **Mesos** etc) is mentioned in master.