# Why is the executors entry not visible in spark web ui

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am running a spark job and even though I've set the the --num-executors parameter to 3 i can't see any executors  in the in the web ui executors tab why is happening

Comment: I've used the command
bin\spark-submit.cmd ^
 --master local[8] ^
 --num-executors 3 ^
 --driver-memory 2G ^
 --executor-memory 2G ^
 --total-executor-cores 2 ^
 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1 ^
 --py-files C:\xyz.py^
  C:\abc.py

Answer (score 1):

Spark in local mode is non-distributed. Spark process will run on single JVM and driver will also behave as an executor.

You can only define number of threads in [master URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356143/what-does-setmaster-local-mean-in-spark).

You can switch to standalone mode.
Start the master using below command:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

And the worker using:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://<host>:7077
```

Now run the spark-submit command.
If you have 6 cores, just specifying `--executor-cores 2` will create 3 executors and you can check the on spark UI.